# Get current geolocation in php mobile web

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a mobile webapp using php. And I need to get current user location i.e the location from where user is accessing the webapp. I have used HTML5 Geolocation for this as following:-

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
     alert("Lat: " + position.coords.latitude + "\nLon: " + position.coords.longitude);
        },
         function(error){
             alert(error.message);
             switch(error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                 alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                  break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                  alert("Location information is unavailable.");
                  break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                  alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                  break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                  alert("An unknown error occurred.");
                  break;
               }

             }, {
                     enableHighAccuracy: true
                     ,timeout : 5000
                 } );
} else { 
    $('#demo').html('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
}
```

But the above code is not working. In firefox it throws

> Unknown error acquiring position

and in chrome I am getting error message

> User denied the request for geolocation

I have checked and location has been enabled in browser settings. I need to use app in mobile so is there any kind of check that can be added in javascript or PHP that asks user to enable location.

Comment: On Firefox , for me it is working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpbdEq

Comment: While trying to run http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpbdEq I faced similar error messages as on my webpage i.e unknown error acquiring position.

Comment: A popup asking to share lcoation appears but after I allow, it do show same error. Did it show your current location?

Comment: yes. I can see my lat and long in a popup. So probably it is something related to your browser/system.